# button taking height of the flexbox div

Tags: css, flexbox

In the following image, the button is taking the height of the flexbox? Why? I want it to be a regular button bottom-aligned with the image on the left (the white square).

[image]

index.css

```
.grid-container{
    display:grid;
    grid-template-rows:[nav-row-start]auto [nav-row-end logo-nav-row-start] auto [logo-nav-row-end content-row-start] auto [content-row-end];


}

.nav-style{
    height:5vh; /*make nav div take 5% of space of viewport*/
    background-color:black;

}

.logo-nav-style{
    height:20vh;/*make logo-nav div take 20% of space of viewport*/
    background-color:gray;
}

.nav-flexbox-container{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:row-reverse;
}

.logo-nav-flexbox-container{
    display:flex;

}
.content-style{
    height:75vh;/*make content div take 75% of space of viewport*/
    background-color:white;
}


#nav{
    grid-row:nav-row-start/nav-row-end;
    margin:0px;
}

#logo-nav{
    grid-row:logo-nav-row-start/logo-nav-row-end;
    margin:0px;
}

#content{
    grid-row:body-row-start/body-row-end;
    margin:0px;
}

#profile-pic {
    margin:5px;
}
#mail-icon-pic{
    margin:5px;
}
#stats-icon-pic{
    margin:5px;
}

#logo-image{
    /*the max width and max height rule will make the image fit inside the div. If the image is bigger than div, the image will
    contract, if the image is smaller than the div, the image will expand*/
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
}
body{
    margin:0px;
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
<title>Something</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="grid-container">
    <div id="nav" class="nav-style nav-flexbox-container">
        <img id="stats-icon-pic" src="stats_icon.png"> 
        <img id="mail-icon-pic" src="mail_icon.png"> 
    </div>
    <div id="logo-nav" class="logo-nav-style logo-nav-flexbox-container">
        <img id="logo-image" src="example_logo.png">
        <button type="button">Questions</button>
    </div>
    <div id="content" class="content-style">body</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `align-items` flexbox property is set to `stretch`. [See CSS tricks on flexbox.](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Use this:

```
.logo-nav-flexbox-container{
    display:flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to add `align-items: flex-end` rule

```
.logo-nav-flexbox-container{
    display:flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
}
```